# Subprocess confuses when passing argument to the bash

Tags: python, subprocess, tshark

Actually i am trying to pass below code to the bash. But i think %s of tshark and pythonic %s are mixing somehow. It gives not enough argument format string error.

```
 def traffic_dest_port(self,filepcap):
    cmd = "tshark -o column.format:'\"Source\", \"%s\", \"Destination\", \"%d\", \"dstport\", \"%uD\"' -r %s |sort|uniq " %filepcap
    subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

Can you help me out on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Two things that would make your code much easier to write, read, and debug: (1) use triple-quoted strings instead of escaping quotes, and (2) let Python do some of the work for you by using [`shlex.quote`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote).

Comment: One thing that would make it even easier: Don't use the shell if you don't need it. See [Replacing shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) in the subprocess docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in your guess. Python's `%` operator will try to replace *every* `%` specifier in the string, not just some of them. Since it finds 4 `%` specifiers, and only one value, it will say `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`.

But, even if it didn't, how did you expect it to guess which one you wanted it to replace out of those four? I'm a human, and even I'm having trouble guessing, so if I guessed wrong, hopefully you can figure out how to adjust the answer to fit your needs.

---

One way around this is to escape the percents you don't want Python to process by doubling them:

```
cmd = "tshark -o column.format:'\"Source\", \"%%s\", \"Destination\", \"%%d\", \"dstport\", \"%%uD\"' -r %s |sort|uniq " %filepcap
```

As described in the documentation on [`printf`-style String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), the specifier `%%` means "No argument is converted, results in a `'%'` character in the result."

And if you print out the result (which you always should when trying to debug stuff like this!), you'll see that the `%s` has been replaced by the `filepcap` value, but the `%%s` has turned into `%s`.

---

However, a much easier solution is to just use a different formatting mechanism that doesn't require `%`, like [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
cmd = "tshark -o column.format:'\"Source\", \"%s\", \"Destination\", \"%d\", \"dstport\", \"%uD\"' -r {} |sort|uniq ".format(filepcap)
```